# animating property changes on vue.js v-for items

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a drive-thru restaurant simulator. Cars are represented as list items in a `vue.js` model. As they progress through the queue, I want to animate their position change. Based on [vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html#Animating-State-with-Watchers) I should use `watch` and `computed` but I don't see a way to use those for `v-for` elements.

```
<div id="app">
<svg width="100%" height="200">
    <g
       v-for="item in allitems"
       v-bind:item="item"
       v-bind:key="item.id">
          <image :x="xx(item.stationIdx, item.placeInLine)" :y="yy(item.placeInLine)" width="80" height="40" :xlink:href="carfile(item.id)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

and the component:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: { 
       allitems : allitems,
    },
    methods: {
        xx: function(istation, placeInLine) {
            // compute the X location of the car based on its current state
            // I'D LIKE TO ANIMATE / TWEEN THIS PROPERTY
           },
        ...
 }
```

Any suggestions on how to animate these?

The change in value is happening on a timer: `setInterval(update_all_items, 1000)`

You can see a codepen example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdrEjj

Using an example right out of the vue.js docs, show the properties changing every seconds, and the jumpiness associated with the updates. This jumpiness I'd like to tween out.

Comment: you want to animate an item when clicked?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing to update them and the data structure, you may need to use `Vue.set`

Comment: transition might be suitable for you depending

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, animated from outside.

codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deNmaX)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg width="100%" height="200">
            <g
                v-for="item in groceryList"
                v-bind:item="item"
                v-bind:key="item.id">
                <text :id="id2elem(item.id)" x="0" :y="yy(item.id)" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">
                    ☞ {{item.text}}
                </text>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <script>

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            groceryList: [
            { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables', x:0 },
            { id: 1, text: 'Cheese', x:0 },
            { id: 2, text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat', x:0 }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            yy: function(id) {
                return 30+id*20;
            },
            id2elem: function(id) {
                return "item_"+id;
            }
        }
    });

    function step() {
        _.each(app.groceryList, function(item){
            item.x +=Math.random() * 10
            item.x = Math.round(item.x + Math.random() * 10);
            var itemid = "#item_"+item.id;
            console.log('tweening item [' + itemid + '] to [' + item.x + ']')
            TweenMax.to(itemid, 1, { attr: {x : ""+item.x}} );
        });
    }
    intervalID = setInterval(step, 1000);

    </script>
</body>
```